# What is the best way to create a script to use with the rails request profiler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, profiling

The rails scirpt `script/performance/request` require a session script, what is the best way to generate this session script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this code to your application.rb file

```
before_filter :benchmark_log

  def benchmark_log
   File.open("request_log.txt","a") do |f|
      f.puts request.method.to_s + " '" + request.request_uri + "', " + params.except(:action).except(:controller).inspect.gsub(/(^\{|\}$)/,"")
    end
  end
```

Then you can visit several pages in your browser, and the session script will be written into the request_log.txt file in your applications root directory